# An error occurred while communicating to the server. jtable in java

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I found this example in this [Curd Operations Link](http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/ajax-based-crud-operations-in-jsp-and-servlet-using-jtable-jquery-plug-in/) when i integrate it to my application data is not bind to the table 
but when i run jsp file it shows one dialogue 
where i did mistake.
Here i am using SqlServer database
[image]

```
Apr 03, 2017 1:19:16 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:BatchManagementSystems' did not find a matching property.
Apr 03, 2017 1:19:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M18
Apr 03, 2017 1:19:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Mar 8 2017 15:20:57 UTC
Apr 03, 2017 1:19:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         9.0.0.0
Apr 03, 2017 1:19:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 8.1
Apr 03, 2017 1:19:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.3
Apr 03, 2017 1:19:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Apr 03, 2017 1:19:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre
Apr 03, 2017 1:19:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_121-b13
Apr 03, 2017 1:19:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Apr 03, 2017 1:19:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         D:\JavaProjects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2
Apr 03, 2017 1:19:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M18
Apr 03, 2017 1:19:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\JavaProjects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2
Apr 03, 2017 1:19:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M18
Apr 03, 2017 1:19:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=D:\JavaProjects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps
Apr 03, 2017 1:19:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M18\endorsed
Apr 03, 2017 1:19:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Apr 03, 2017 1:19:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;.;;C:\Users\Lakshmich\Desktop;;.
Apr 03, 2017 1:19:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-89"]
Apr 03, 2017 1:19:21 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Apr 03, 2017 1:19:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Apr 03, 2017 1:19:21 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Apr 03, 2017 1:19:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 7144 ms
Apr 03, 2017 1:19:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 03, 2017 1:19:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M18
Apr 03, 2017 1:19:23 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Apr 03, 2017 1:19:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-89]
Apr 03, 2017 1:19:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
Apr 03, 2017 1:19:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2689 ms
```

Jsp:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#UserRegistration').jtable({
        title : 'User Registration',
        paging: false, //Enable paging
        //pageSize: 3, //Set page size (default: 10)           
        actions : {
            listAction: 'Controller?action=list',
           // createAction:'Controller?action=create',
            updateAction: 'Controller?action=update',
            deleteAction: 'Controller?action=delete'                      
  },
        fields : {
            UserId : {
                title : 'UserId Id',
                //sort :true,
                //width : '30%'             
            },
            FirstName : {
                title : 'FirstName',
                //width : '30%',
                edit : true
            },

            LastName : {
                title : 'LastName',
                //width : '30%',
                edit : true
            },
            MiddleName : {
                title : 'MiddleName',
                //width : '30%',
                edit : true
            },

            EmailID : {
                title : 'EmailID',
                //width : '30%',
                edit : true
            },
            Role : {
                title : 'Role',
                //width : '20%',
                edit : true
            },
            EmployeeId:{
                title:'Employee Id',
                //width:'20%',
                edit:true

            }
        }

    });
    $('#UserRegistration').jtable('load');
});
</script>
```

Following controller list method

```
String action = request.getParameter("action");
        List<UserRegistration> UsertList = new ArrayList<UserRegistration>();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        //String jsonArray = gson.toJson(JSONROOT);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        HashMap<String, Object> JSONROOT = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        if(action.equals("list")){
            try{                        
                //Fetch Data from User Table
                UsertList=dao.getAllUsers();
                //Return in the format required by jTable plugin
                JSONROOT.put("Result", "OK");
                JSONROOT.put("Records", UsertList);
             // Convert Java Object to Json
                String jsonArray = gson.toJson(JSONROOT);
                System.out.println(jsonArray);
                response.getWriter().print(jsonArray);

                }catch(Exception ex){
                     JSONROOT.put("Result", "ERROR");
                     JSONROOT.put("Message", ex.getMessage());
                     String error = gson.toJson(JSONROOT);
                     response.getWriter().print(error);
                }
        }
```

Comment: Check for the browser console errors,it must be more detailed

Comment: could you please tell me i am getting error

Comment: Let us say for chrome broswer->Right click-inpect element->Click on console tab in the window that shows at the bottom,you will have some errors,providing detailed description